# How can I add customized text labels to a ggplot2 plot with a date x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, text

I tried to add an annotation to a plot using ggplot2 package in R

```r
pt1 +
  ggplot2::annotate("text", x = as.Date("2022-01-01"), y = 4, label = "p < 0.0001", color = "black")
```

Where x is a date variable. After making a plot with ggplot2 package, I want to add a text on the plot, however the x variable is a date variable, so we should use as.Date function and specify the coordinates of the text on the plot.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the question is? Why isn't what you've tried working? Please also share the code and data you used to create `pt1` if you have a question.